# Recurrence relationship $F(n+2)-2F(n+1)-8F(n)=0$

Tags: derivatives, recurrence-relations

$$F(n+2)-2F(n+1)-8F(n)=0$$
Our solution is trigonometric algebraic $$ 2^n(2^n-\cos(\pi n)) $$
My question is as fallow, can we find solution to this recurrence relation that has solution $$ F^\text{(m)}(n)=F(n) $$ where $m$ is mth derivative mainly ($m=0,1,2,3$) and this two are not equal every where conditionally most specifically where $n=0,1,2,3,\dots$
What is the best way to go about this?.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  This is a standard sort of linear recurrence...its characteristic polynomial is $x^2-2x-8$ which has roots $-2,4$.  Thus the general solution is $F_n=A\times (-2)^n+B\times 4^n$.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: If you are looking for a reference on problems of this sort, try [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Characteristic_polynomial).

Comment: no I'm looking for function that $$ ...=F''(0)=F'(0)=F(0),  ...=F''(1)=F'(1)=F(1) $$

Comment: Not following.  I suggest you edit your post for clarity.  What exactly are you asking?  I have written out the general solution to your recursion...what is left to say about it?